# Overwrote a file in Sharepoint 2013. How can I recover it?

Tags: sharepoint

I did check both Recycle Bins (Stage 1 and 2), and the old version wasn't there. I think this is because I overwrote the file, instead of deleting it. Is there any other place to look?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn’t Sharepoint be configured to keep previous versions? Not in any recycle bin, but the file itself.

Comment: There is no way to recover the data. You didn't delete it, so it does not exist on the HDD, since it was never marked for deletion. The only possible way would be to use shadow copy if it was turned on, but if file history wasnt turned on or sharepoint prevents shadow copy from working you are out of luck.

Comment: From Microsoft: [View, restore, or delete a previous version of a file or item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-server-help/view-restore-or-delete-a-previous-version-of-a-file-or-item-HA102771930.aspx?CTT=1). If you didn't have versioning turned on, you're probably SOL.

Comment: Yep, that was the conclusion I came to as well. Luckily not too much data was lost. Versioning was not on because the site is too large (error message due to large number of files). Splitting up the site further right now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless you had SharePoint versioning turned on or if someone has a local copy I'm afraid it's not possible to recover the file.